# Rails 5 Subscribing to Action Cable channel from ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I've been trying to show all conversation messages without refreshing page just with an ajax request. With this code i'm able to send message with channel but i'm not able to receive the message.

I would like to pass dynamically ID from frontend. I know it's possible to make that with a data parameter added into the body tag ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971431/how-to-set-params-when-subscribing-to-action-cable-channel?answertab=active#tab-top)).

I would like make the same but when i click on a conversation that change body data "conversation-id" and subscribe to the new channel id. I hope it's possible to make that with rails 5/jquery(ajax).

Here's my code :

**conversation.coffee**

```
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create channel: "ConversationChannel", id: document.querySelector('#conversation').dataset.conversationId,
  connected: ->
    $('#new_message').submit (e) ->
      $this = $(this)
      id = $this.find('#message_conversation_id');
      body = $this.find('#message_body')
      App.conversation.write id.val(), body.val()
      body.val('')
      e.preventDefault()
      return false

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    $('.box-msg').append(data.data)

  write: (id, body) ->
    @perform 'write', {id: id, body: body}
```

**conversation_channel.rb**

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
      id = "[HOW CAN I PASS DYNAMICALLY ID]" 
      if id #on stream seulement si id existe
        stream_from "conversation_#{id}"
      end
    end

    def unsubscribed
      # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    end
    def write(data)
        msg = Message.create(
          conversation_id: data["id"], 
          body: data['body'], 
          user_id: 41,
          read: 0
        )
        if msg.save 
          html = ApplicationController.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: msg})
        end
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{data["id"]}", data: html
    end
  end
```

**conversations/index.html.erb**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.card-conversation').click(function() {
            $("#conversation-content").html('');
            var id = $(this).data("conversation");
            $("body").attr("data-conversation-id", id);
            $("#message_conversation_id").val(id); //input id 
            $.ajax({
                url: "/conversations/"+id+"/messages",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#conversation-content").append(html);
                }
            });
            $("#conversation-content").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="row h-100 no-margin">   
    <div class="col-md-4 h-100 messages-list" style="padding-right: 2px !important;">
            <% @conversations.first(3).each do |conversation| %>
                <div class="card card-conversation" data-conversation="<%=conversation.id %>">
                   <p>see conversation</p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 conversation no-padding" id="conversation">
        <div id="conversation-content"></div>
          <%= simple_form_for Message.new, url: "#" do |f| %>
              <%= f.input :body, label: false, placeholder: "Add msg" %>
              <%= f.input :conversation_id, label: false %>
              <%= f.submit 'Go' %>
          <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```